# Renault car (2003) remote control signal is not received by rc receiver (rcswitch)

Tags: arduino-uno

I have an arduino uno, I have set up a rf receiver as well known library rcswitch suggests I do, but I can never see something on the serial monitor in the IDE environment. I am using the example provided by the library, and did the pin set-up as described.
The key (car card) is that of an old Renault Laguna 2. I have browsed the web and am pretty sure that it sends an rf 433mhz signal, and my receiver is also listening to that frequency, so I am quite surprised that nothing pops up.
I also have a transmitter but only 1 dev board so can't really think of any way to test the receiver. Any suggestions ? In case the receiver might be broken how can it be tested? Am quite new to this.
Any help appreciated

Comment: 433MHz is just the name of the band. You need the receiver to be tuned to the exact frequency the key fob transmits on - and then it needs to decode the data in the right way to make some sense of it.

Comment: Step one with any unknown transmitter is to buy a cheap USB SDR dongle and analyse the radio signal.

Comment: @Majenko thanks for the answers.but i was looking for a way to do it without buying nothing else. i was lookin thru the rfswitch lib and I don't see where it sets the frequenct on which to listen on, is this the same as setting the protocol ?

Comment: The frequency is set by the receiver module. If that doesn't match the transmitter it won't receive anything at all.